# DBX error with running 32-bit app on 64 bit windows

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am using Delphi Berlin 10.1 to compile an app for Windows 32 bit. When clients use oracle 32 bit instant client on Windows 64 bit, they get this error:

> "Could not connect to  (DBX Error: driver could not be
> properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed
> properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the
> system path.)"

A way that I use to fix the problem works for some users:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 midas.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 dbxora.dl
C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32 midas.dll
C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32 dbxora.dll
```

But for other 64 bit users I have not found the solution to the DBX error. The app always works correctly on Windows 32 bit. I have compiled the app in 64 bit as well, but some users still get the DBX error. Databases are oracle 12 and 19 connecting from windows clients to unix.

Comment: One option is to place the required instant client DLLs/files in the same directory as your executable. Note that Oracle does not support installing 64bit and 32bit clients at the same time so it is usually better to not even to try sharing client installs between applications.

Comment: Hi it is only the oracle 32 bit client. It is windows 64 bit. Are you saying I must find the correct oracle 32 bit client DLLs and put them together with my app exe?